# virsh console hangs at the escape character "^]"

Tags: console, virtual-machine

I am trying to kickstart a newly built VM. I am stuck with the following. 
Want to start with a console so that I can include username and other info for this VM:

```
   @vmhost02 ~]$ sudo virsh start --console testengine
   Domain testengine started
   Connected to domain testengine
   Escape character is ^]
```

It hangs up in there and doesn't listen to any keys except "^]"

Let me know if you need more information for any ideas...

Thanks very much.

Comment: Problem Solved... Missing symlink in the pxelinux.cfg area for the 'testengine.host.org'

Comment: Why dont you describe how to solve that error so you can help anyone else?

Answer (score 9):

### 1)

You can try to edit `/etc/default/grub` in the guest, and make sure you have:

```
GRUB_TERMINAL=serial
GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="serial --unit=0 --speed=115200 --word=8 --parity=no --stop=1"
```

Then execute:

```
# update-grub
# reboot
```

### 2)

If that does not work, try to replace `quiet` with `console=ttyS0` in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="... console=ttyS0"
```

Then again:

```
# update-grub
# reboot
```

### 3)

You may still need to try:

```
# systemctl enable serial-getty@ttyS0.service
# systemctl start serial-getty@ttyS0.service
# reboot
```

Comment: In centos 7 `update-grub` is `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`

Comment: How can I edit files in the guest when I have no console to it? It hangs in the installer

Answer (score 6):

You would need to define a tty to be used as a virtual console. In case you have access to your vm either using vnc or ssh create the following file

```
vi /etc/init/ttyS0.conf
```

The content should be something like

```
start on stopped rc RUNLEVEL=[2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
exec /sbin/getty -L 38400 ttyS0 vt102  # This is your term type vt102
```

Save these settings and subsequently from your host machine

```
 virsh destroy [vm-name]; service libvirtd stop; service libvirtd start; virsh start [vm-name]
```

I'm doing here a  stop/start of libvirt, because it sometimes tend to not send a SIGTERM to libvirt.

Finally try

```
 virsh console [vm-name]
```

Comment: I don't have SSH access to the vm, neither vnc.

Comment: /sbin/agetty is both on Debian and CentOS based distros.

Comment: @val0x00ff Hi - service stop libvirtd -> should this be service libvirtd stop; service libvirtd start ?

Comment: @JeremyHajek  You are absolutely correct! I edited the answer. In the future feel free to edit the answer and correct mistakes if necessary. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

May be simpler than the solution of val0x00ff, you shall add the `console=ttyS0` at the end of the kernel lines in the `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` file of the VM (this is not done by default it seems):

```
   (vm)$> grubby --update-kernel=ALL --args="console=ttyS0"
   (vm)$> reboot
```

Then `virsh console` shall work as expected.

Comment: This did the job for me, albeit I edited `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` by hand to append the kernel parameter (editing `grub.cfg` is a non-permanent solution, I know, the file is generated).